# Claims is empty and user is not Authenticated in HandleRequirement of AuthorizationHandlerContext with Duende identity server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I am using Asp.net core 6 with Duenda Identity server

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager serviceConfiguration = builder.Configuration;
builder.Services.ConfigureIdentityServer(serviceConfiguration);

services.AddAuthentication(AuthorizePolicy.TokenSchema)
                .AddJwtBearer(AuthorizePolicy.TokenSchema, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Now in the handler, the claims are empty. The request has Bearer token in it.

```
   public class IdentityServerUserClaimHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IdentityServerUserClaimRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            IdentityServerUserClaimRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == requirement.ClaimType &&
                                           c.Value == requirement.ClaimValue))
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Access token encode from jwt.io

```
{
  "iss": "https://localhost:5001",
  "nbf": 1651574541,
  "iat": 1651574541,
  "exp": 1651574741,
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "client_id": "Falcon_Identity_Server",
  "sub": "9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988",
  "auth_time": 1651574539,
  "idp": "local",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "admin@local.com",
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "admin@local.com",
  "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp": "1999ca9c-398d-4ffe-907a-b1f1b5e8cbfe",
  "identityserver": "owner",
  "fb_product": "owner",
  "fb_order": "owner",
  "fb_payment": "owner",
  "sid": "716EA1A6F89D0A014DDCE43B5B66190F",
  "jti": "6417334FFDDB45054A77348952135CE4"
}
```

**Update**

Remove the Token schema, now I have only cookies schema as below

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

**Logs from Identity server**

```
2022-05-05 18:21:45.905 +10:00 [INF] Starting Duende IdentityServer version 6.1.0-preview.3+6a45df770da336604801bddca593a902f1ccb802 (.NET 6.0.3)
2022-05-05 18:21:45.924 +10:00 [WRN] You do not have a valid license key for the Duende software. This is allowed for development and testing scenarios. If you are running in production you are required to have a licensed version. Please start a conversation with us: https://duendesoftware.com/contact
2022-05-05 18:21:45.931 +10:00 [INF] Using the default authentication scheme Cookies for IdentityServer
2022-05-05 18:21:45.931 +10:00 [DBG] Using Cookies as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication
2022-05-05 18:21:45.931 +10:00 [DBG] Using Cookies as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in
2022-05-05 18:21:45.931 +10:00 [DBG] Using Cookies as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out
2022-05-05 18:21:45.931 +10:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge
2022-05-05 18:21:45.931 +10:00 [DBG] Using Cookies as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
2022-05-05 18:21:46.065 +10:00 [WRN] You do not have a valid license key for the Duende software. This is allowed for development and testing scenarios. If you are running in production you are required to have a licensed version. Please start a conversation with us: https://duendesoftware.com/contact
2022-05-05 18:21:46.222 +10:00 [INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
2022-05-05 18:21:46.222 +10:00 [INF] Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
2022-05-05 18:21:46.223 +10:00 [INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2022-05-05 18:21:46.224 +10:00 [INF] Hosting environment: Development
2022-05-05 18:21:46.224 +10:00 [INF] Content root path: /Users/san/project/Sample/Falcon-Identity/Falcon-Identity/
2022-05-05 18:21:53.225 +10:00 [DBG] Login Url: /Account/Login
2022-05-05 18:21:53.227 +10:00 [DBG] Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl
2022-05-05 18:21:53.227 +10:00 [DBG] Logout Url: /Account/Logout
2022-05-05 18:21:53.227 +10:00 [DBG] ConsentUrl Url: /consent
2022-05-05 18:21:53.227 +10:00 [DBG] Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl
2022-05-05 18:21:53.227 +10:00 [DBG] Error Url: /home/error
2022-05-05 18:21:53.227 +10:00 [DBG] Error Id Parameter: errorId
2022-05-05 18:21:53.273 +10:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: https://localhost:5002
2022-05-05 18:21:53.333 +10:00 [DBG] Origin https://localhost:5002 is allowed: true
2022-05-05 18:21:53.334 +10:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: https://localhost:5002
2022-05-05 18:21:53.346 +10:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2022-05-05 18:21:53.347 +10:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2022-05-05 18:21:53.349 +10:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2022-05-05 18:21:53.350 +10:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2022-05-05 18:21:53.443 +10:00 [INF] Active signing key found with kid C1C7E591CAF7B3C98C7ECACE9B6A6AC3 for alg RS256. Expires in "83.22:18:15". Retires in "97.22:18:15"
2022-05-05 18:21:53.478 +10:00 [DBG] Retrieve AuthenticationTicket for key E1183024D7FD528A15F9313DD6985CBA9C6E3D0B90C33469371D8C392B9F604B
2022-05-05 18:21:53.479 +10:00 [DBG] No ticket found in store for E1183024D7FD528A15F9313DD6985CBA9C6E3D0B90C33469371D8C392B9F604B
2022-05-05 18:21:53.480 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.481 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.482 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.487 +10:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
2022-05-05 18:21:53.496 +10:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2022-05-05 18:21:53.497 +10:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
2022-05-05 18:21:53.498 +10:00 [DBG] Start authorize request
2022-05-05 18:21:53.503 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.505 +10:00 [DBG] No user present in authorize request
2022-05-05 18:21:53.505 +10:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2022-05-05 18:21:53.781 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:21:53.784 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:21:53.788 +10:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2022-05-05 18:21:53.796 +10:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2022-05-05 18:21:53.802 +10:00 [DBG] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{"ClientId":"Falcon_Identity_Server","ClientName":"FalconIdentityServer","RedirectUri":"https://localhost:5002/auth-callback","AllowedRedirectUris":["http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-renew.html","http://localhost:4200/auth-callback","https://falconidentity.azurewebsites.net/assets/silent-callback.html","https://falconidentity.azurewebsites.net/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html","https://localhost:5001/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html","https://localhost:5002/assets/silent-callback.html","https://localhost:5002/auth-callback","https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback"],"SubjectId":"anonymous","ResponseType":"code","ResponseMode":"query","GrantType":"authorization_code","RequestedScopes":"openid profile email","State":"aa753cd62b164242a2f04591b6bb0679","UiLocales":null,"Nonce":null,"AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses":null,"DisplayMode":null,"PromptMode":"","MaxAge":null,"LoginHint":null,"SessionId":"","Raw":{"client_id":"Falcon_Identity_Server","redirect_uri":"https://localhost:5002/auth-callback","response_type":"code","scope":"openid profile email","state":"aa753cd62b164242a2f04591b6bb0679","code_challenge":"jD4jnETjtjqswT7vJTTPMpDSegpDpX7L7L3plAueqdI","code_challenge_method":"S256","response_mode":"query"},"$type":"AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}
2022-05-05 18:21:53.809 +10:00 [INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
2022-05-05 18:21:53.814 +10:00 [DBG] Retrieve AuthenticationTicket for key E1183024D7FD528A15F9313DD6985CBA9C6E3D0B90C33469371D8C392B9F604B
2022-05-05 18:21:53.815 +10:00 [DBG] No ticket found in store for E1183024D7FD528A15F9313DD6985CBA9C6E3D0B90C33469371D8C392B9F604B
2022-05-05 18:21:53.815 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.816 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.817 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.875 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.876 +10:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2022-05-05 18:21:53.942 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:21:53.942 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:21:53.942 +10:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2022-05-05 18:21:53.942 +10:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2022-05-05 18:21:54.047 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:21:54.047 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:22:07.023 +10:00 [DBG] Retrieve AuthenticationTicket for key E1183024D7FD528A15F9313DD6985CBA9C6E3D0B90C33469371D8C392B9F604B
2022-05-05 18:22:07.023 +10:00 [DBG] No ticket found in store for E1183024D7FD528A15F9313DD6985CBA9C6E3D0B90C33469371D8C392B9F604B
2022-05-05 18:22:07.023 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:22:07.024 +10:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /Account/Login from origin: null but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint
2022-05-05 18:22:07.024 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:22:07.025 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:22:07.055 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:22:07.055 +10:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2022-05-05 18:22:07.199 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:22:07.199 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:22:07.199 +10:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2022-05-05 18:22:07.199 +10:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2022-05-05 18:22:07.466 +10:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
2022-05-05 18:22:07.477 +10:00 [DBG] Augmenting SignInContext
2022-05-05 18:22:07.478 +10:00 [DBG] Adding idp claim with value: local
2022-05-05 18:22:07.478 +10:00 [DBG] Adding amr claim with value: pwd
2022-05-05 18:22:07.478 +10:00 [DBG] Adding auth_time claim with value: 1651738927
2022-05-05 18:22:07.478 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:22:07.479 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:22:07.485 +10:00 [DBG] Creating entry in store for AuthenticationTicket, key C1BEC550ECB78D2E76A8FEFA6489CA9648CE9919F78115615A58A4B762D48598, with expiration: "2022-05-19T08:22:07.0000000Z"
2022-05-05 18:22:07.492 +10:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
2022-05-05 18:22:07.495 +10:00 [DBG] Retrieve AuthenticationTicket for key C1BEC550ECB78D2E76A8FEFA6489CA9648CE9919F78115615A58A4B762D48598
2022-05-05 18:22:07.496 +10:00 [DBG] Ticket loaded for key: C1BEC550ECB78D2E76A8FEFA6489CA9648CE9919F78115615A58A4B762D48598, with expiration: "2022-05-19T08:22:07.0000000Z"
2022-05-05 18:22:07.499 +10:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/authorize/callback matched to endpoint type Authorize
2022-05-05 18:22:07.499 +10:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
2022-05-05 18:22:07.500 +10:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
2022-05-05 18:22:07.501 +10:00 [DBG] Start authorize callback request
2022-05-05 18:22:07.501 +10:00 [DBG] User in authorize request: 9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988
2022-05-05 18:22:07.501 +10:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2022-05-05 18:22:07.758 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:22:07.758 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:22:07.758 +10:00 [DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
2022-05-05 18:22:07.758 +10:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2022-05-05 18:22:07.763 +10:00 [DBG] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{"ClientId":"Falcon_Identity_Server","ClientName":"FalconIdentityServer","RedirectUri":"https://localhost:5002/auth-callback","AllowedRedirectUris":["http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-renew.html","http://localhost:4200/auth-callback","https://falconidentity.azurewebsites.net/assets/silent-callback.html","https://falconidentity.azurewebsites.net/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html","https://localhost:5001/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html","https://localhost:5002/assets/silent-callback.html","https://localhost:5002/auth-callback","https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback"],"SubjectId":"9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988","ResponseType":"code","ResponseMode":"query","GrantType":"authorization_code","RequestedScopes":"openid profile email","State":"aa753cd62b164242a2f04591b6bb0679","UiLocales":null,"Nonce":null,"AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses":null,"DisplayMode":null,"PromptMode":"","MaxAge":null,"LoginHint":null,"SessionId":"C179DA1B9A4A6B426EB92E47F7AB9F6A","Raw":{"client_id":"Falcon_Identity_Server","redirect_uri":"https://localhost:5002/auth-callback","response_type":"code","scope":"openid profile email","state":"aa753cd62b164242a2f04591b6bb0679","code_challenge":"jD4jnETjtjqswT7vJTTPMpDSegpDpX7L7L3plAueqdI","code_challenge_method":"S256","response_mode":"query"},"$type":"AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}
2022-05-05 18:22:07.851 +10:00 [DBG] Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
2022-05-05 18:22:07.853 +10:00 [DBG] Creating Authorization Code Flow response.
2022-05-05 18:22:07.903 +10:00 [DBG] 3A181978EF26F0DB98A1B2D2509C5ACF958EB7B4450AA81443F5F2C8B6572EDC not found in database
2022-05-05 18:22:08.039 +10:00 [DBG] Authorize endpoint response
{"SubjectId":"9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988","ClientId":"Falcon_Identity_Server","RedirectUri":"https://localhost:5002/auth-callback","State":"aa753cd62b164242a2f04591b6bb0679","Scope":"openid profile email","Error":null,"ErrorDescription":null,"$type":"AuthorizeResponseLog"}
2022-05-05 18:22:08.042 +10:00 [DBG] Augmenting SignInContext
2022-05-05 18:22:08.043 +10:00 [DBG] Renewing AuthenticationTicket for key C1BEC550ECB78D2E76A8FEFA6489CA9648CE9919F78115615A58A4B762D48598, with expiration: "2022-05-19T08:22:07.0000000Z"
2022-05-05 18:22:08.043 +10:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
2022-05-05 18:22:08.231 +10:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: https://localhost:5002
2022-05-05 18:22:08.244 +10:00 [DBG] Origin https://localhost:5002 is allowed: true
2022-05-05 18:22:08.244 +10:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: https://localhost:5002
2022-05-05 18:22:08.244 +10:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2022-05-05 18:22:08.244 +10:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2022-05-05 18:22:08.245 +10:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2022-05-05 18:22:08.246 +10:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2022-05-05 18:22:08.247 +10:00 [INF] Active signing key found with kid C1C7E591CAF7B3C98C7ECACE9B6A6AC3 for alg RS256. Expires in "83.22:18:00". Retires in "97.22:18:00"
2022-05-05 18:22:08.253 +10:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /connect/token from origin: https://localhost:5002
2022-05-05 18:22:08.304 +10:00 [DBG] Origin https://localhost:5002 is allowed: true
2022-05-05 18:22:08.304 +10:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: https://localhost:5002
2022-05-05 18:22:08.305 +10:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/token matched to endpoint type Token
2022-05-05 18:22:08.307 +10:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Token, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
2022-05-05 18:22:08.308 +10:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint for /connect/token
2022-05-05 18:22:08.310 +10:00 [DBG] Start token request.
2022-05-05 18:22:08.311 +10:00 [DBG] Start client validation
2022-05-05 18:22:08.312 +10:00 [DBG] Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2022-05-05 18:22:08.312 +10:00 [DBG] Start parsing for secret in post body
2022-05-05 18:22:08.312 +10:00 [DBG] client id without secret found
2022-05-05 18:22:08.312 +10:00 [DBG] Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser
2022-05-05 18:22:08.313 +10:00 [DBG] Secret id found: Falcon_Identity_Server
2022-05-05 18:22:08.564 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:22:08.565 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:22:08.567 +10:00 [DBG] Public Client - skipping secret validation success
2022-05-05 18:22:08.567 +10:00 [DBG] Client validation success
2022-05-05 18:22:08.578 +10:00 [DBG] Start token request validation
2022-05-05 18:22:08.586 +10:00 [DBG] Start validation of authorization code token request
2022-05-05 18:22:08.613 +10:00 [DBG] 3A181978EF26F0DB98A1B2D2509C5ACF958EB7B4450AA81443F5F2C8B6572EDC found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:22:08.629 +10:00 [DBG] removing 3A181978EF26F0DB98A1B2D2509C5ACF958EB7B4450AA81443F5F2C8B6572EDC persisted grant from database
2022-05-05 18:22:08.649 +10:00 [DBG] Client required a proof key for code exchange. Starting PKCE validation
2022-05-05 18:22:08.654 +10:00 [DBG] Validation of authorization code token request success
2022-05-05 18:22:08.660 +10:00 [INF] Token request validation success, {"ClientId":"Falcon_Identity_Server","ClientName":"FalconIdentityServer","GrantType":"authorization_code","Scopes":null,"AuthorizationCode":"****76-1","RefreshToken":"********","UserName":null,"AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses":null,"Tenant":null,"IdP":null,"Raw":{"client_id":"Falcon_Identity_Server","code":"01F5B7A646A2C431F5F1329346846EF5BDE4A4A9103C3A2E56CFB2B6BCD61676-1","redirect_uri":"https://localhost:5002/auth-callback","code_verifier":"81c77066c9c1467b9fc4a3552869c834151bd60fa0064f708eafbb1f77a7aea5c46e71b9e5c84e93a3056d8d80ee146b","grant_type":"authorization_code"},"$type":"TokenRequestValidationLog"}
2022-05-05 18:22:08.792 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:22:08.792 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:22:08.795 +10:00 [DBG] Getting claims for access token for client: Falcon_Identity_Server
2022-05-05 18:22:08.796 +10:00 [DBG] Getting claims for access token for subject: 9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988
2022-05-05 18:22:08.811 +10:00 [DBG] Claim types from profile service that were filtered: ["sub"]
2022-05-05 18:22:09.011 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:22:09.011 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:22:09.014 +10:00 [DBG] Getting claims for identity token for subject: 9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988 and client: Falcon_Identity_Server
2022-05-05 18:22:09.014 +10:00 [DBG] In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client configuration.
2022-05-05 18:22:09.017 +10:00 [DBG] Token request success.
2022-05-05 18:22:09.024 +10:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /connect/userinfo from origin: https://localhost:5002
2022-05-05 18:22:09.034 +10:00 [DBG] Origin https://localhost:5002 is allowed: true
2022-05-05 18:22:09.034 +10:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: https://localhost:5002
2022-05-05 18:22:09.034 +10:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/userinfo matched to endpoint type Userinfo
2022-05-05 18:22:09.035 +10:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Userinfo, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint
2022-05-05 18:22:09.036 +10:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint for /connect/userinfo
2022-05-05 18:22:09.037 +10:00 [DBG] Start userinfo request
2022-05-05 18:22:09.038 +10:00 [DBG] Bearer token found in header
2022-05-05 18:22:09.188 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:22:09.188 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:22:09.311 +10:00 [DBG] Falcon_Identity_Server found in database: true
2022-05-05 18:22:09.311 +10:00 [DBG] client configuration validation for client Falcon_Identity_Server succeeded.
2022-05-05 18:22:09.321 +10:00 [DBG] Calling into custom token validator: Duende.IdentityServer.Validation.DefaultCustomTokenValidator
2022-05-05 18:22:09.322 +10:00 [DBG] Token validation success
{"ClientId":null,"ClientName":null,"ValidateLifetime":true,"AccessTokenType":"Jwt","ExpectedScope":"openid","TokenHandle":null,"JwtId":"614C94729DCAAA8A4D821A6CB515CADF","Claims":{"iss":"https://localhost:5001","nbf":1651738928,"iat":1651738928,"exp":1651739128,"scope":["openid","profile","email"],"amr":"pwd","client_id":"Falcon_Identity_Server","sub":"9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988","auth_time":1651738927,"idp":"local","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier":"9717a359-f83b-43b3-97b3-2f04f1148988","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name":"admin@local.com","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress":"admin@local.com","AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp":"1999ca9c-398d-4ffe-907a-b1f1b5e8cbfe","identityserver":"owner","fb_product":"owner","fb_order":"owner","fb_payment":"owner","sid":"C179DA1B9A4A6B426EB92E47F7AB9F6A","jti":"614C94729DCAAA8A4D821A6CB515CADF"},"$type":"TokenValidationLog"}
2022-05-05 18:22:09.324 +10:00 [DBG] Creating userinfo response
2022-05-05 18:22:09.325 +10:00 [DBG] Scopes in access token: openid profile email
2022-05-05 18:22:09.326 +10:00 [DBG] Requested claim types: 
2022-05-05 18:22:09.381 +10:00 [INF] Profile service returned the following claim types: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp sub identityserver fb_product fb_order fb_payment
2022-05-05 18:22:09.381 +10:00 [DBG] End userinfo request
2022-05-05 18:22:09.397 +10:00 [DBG] Retrieve AuthenticationTicket for key C1BEC550ECB78D2E76A8FEFA6489CA9648CE9919F78115615A58A4B762D48598
2022-05-05 18:22:09.398 +10:00 [DBG] Ticket loaded for key: C1BEC550ECB78D2E76A8FEFA6489CA9648CE9919F78115615A58A4B762D48598, with expiration: "2022-05-19T08:22:07.0000000Z"
2022-05-05 18:22:09.398 +10:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/checksession matched to endpoint type Checksession
2022-05-05 18:22:09.399 +10:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Checksession, successfully created handler: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint
2022-05-05 18:22:09.399 +10:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: Duende.IdentityServer.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint for /connect/checksession
2022-05-05 18:22:09.400 +10:00 [DBG] Rendering check session result
2022-05-05 18:22:12.315 +10:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /UserManagement/GetAllUsers from origin: https://localhost:5002 but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint
2022-05-05 18:22:12.348 +10:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
2022-05-05 18:22:12.352 +10:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /Account/Login from origin: https://localhost:5002 but was ignored because path was not for an allowed IdentityServer CORS endpoint
```

**From above log**

```
2022-05-05 18:21:53.482 +10:00 [INF] Cookies was not authenticated. Failure message: Identity missing in session store
2022-05-05 18:21:53.505 +10:00 [DBG] No user present in authorize request
2022-05-05 18:21:53.479 +10:00 [DBG] No ticket found in store for E1183024D7FD528A15F9313DD6985CBA9C6E3D0B90C33469371D8C392B9F604B
```

Comment: Please paste a sample access token to your quesition, probably you need to do some claims mapping to map the claims in the token to the ClaimsPrinicpal user

Comment: @ToreNestenius added the access token

Comment: My golden rule for IdentityServer is to place the client, API and identityServer in separate services, when you mix them together, you will have pain, suffering and missery trying to  reason about the behavour of the system.  In your case, you have both a session cookie and token involved and when the service receives the cookie and token, who will win?

Comment: @ToreNestenius I have removed the token schema, still getting the same issue, Updated the question in update section

Comment: i suspect that the app.UseIdentityServer(); sees the incoming request with its session cookie and then it creates a user out of that and because of that AddJwtBearer is no longer needed. I still suggest you put the API on its own service. ,see https://www.dominikzoechbauer.com/blog/2021-02-20/combining-and-cookie-jwt-bearer-authentication/

Comment: @ToreNestenius Thank you for the help, what do you mean by put the API on its own service ?

Comment: put the API in its own ASP.NET Core instance. I recommend that you put the client, identityServer and your API in separate ASP.NET Core projects, then its much easier to reasoning about the system and troubleshoot.

Comment: @ToreNestenius - I have added logs, quite not sure how to fix that

Comment: As I said in my answer, I would put the three things into separate services and not combined.... in your case, when you send in your access token, IdentityServer sees that there is a cookie, and it uses that instead of passing the request further to AddJwtBearer....

Comment: @ToreNestenius I understand you point, but I cannot separate the project it is requirement to have one project, However, if I set [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] in each controller to work, how can I register this by default. It is taking cookies default schema

Comment: Perhaps this post can help you ? https://www.dominikzoechbauer.com/blog/2021-02-20/combining-and-cookie-jwt-bearer-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

To better troubleshoot your system I recommend that you place your client application, IdentityServer and your API in separate ASP.NET Core projects.

Why? It makes your system much easier to reason about, troubleshoot and understand.

I think the main point is that when you build an identity solution, you must understand it and when you put it all in one service, its really hard to understand.